# Is there an acyclic closed manifold (for integral homology)?

Tags: manifolds

A space is **acyclic** if the reduced integral homology groups are all trivial.

I want to know whether there exists a closed manifold which is acyclic.

A necessary condition is that this manifold will not be orientable.
Another necessary condition is that it will not be a surface because of the known results about classifications of closed surfaces.

So the question becomes:
Is there a non-orientable **acyclic closed manifold** of dimension 3 or more?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume you don't allow boundary?

Comment: yes I require a compact manifold without boundary.

Comment: In some sense, this is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606611/first-homology-group-of-non-orientable-manifold because that MSE question and answer establish that non-orientable implies non-acyclic.  If you want, you can write up your own answer.